# Convert JavaScript code to VBScript code?

Tags: javascript, vbscript, code-conversion

I have been given a task to convert code that is written in JavaScript over to VBScript.
It is actually quite basic code and it is really just the syntax that needs to be converted.

For example

```
 if (str == "string text") {
   foo = "foo";
} else {
   foo2 = "foo2";
}
```

becomes

```
 If (str = "string text") Then
   foo = "foo"
Else
   foo2 = "foo2"
End If
```

I was wondering if a tool existed to convert from JavaScript to VBScript?

Comment: can i be the first one to say: why on god's good earth would you want to convert TO vbscript???

Comment: heh, i know it's a strange situation, but basically due to legacy support

Comment: can i be the second one to say: why on god's good earth would you want to convert TO vbscript???   ;-)

Comment: On this God's good Earth, I am the second one who desperately wants convert JS script to VBS :)

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569380/how-can-i-convert-javascript-to-vbscript